# Implementing a splay tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, splay-tree

I am trying to implement splay tree. The code goes into infinite loop printing

> 20 10 20 15 10 20 15 15 10 10 20 15
> for below test code and it goes on repeating itself.
> I have tried debugging but i cannot find where it is going wrong. The code runs fine if i go on inserting nodes in a skewed manner. For Example : if i do not insert 1 at the last it does well but as soon as it goes unskewed it creates problem.

Here is my code

> splay_tree.h

```
#include<queue>
#include<iostream>
#include"node.h"


template<class T>
class splay_tree{
private:
 Node<T>* root=nullptr;

public:
   splay_tree(){
       root=nullptr;
   }
 //gethead
 Node<T>* gethead(){
     return this->root;
 }
 //left rotate
 void left_rotate(Node<T>* node){
     if(node==nullptr){return ;}
     else{
         Node<T>* temp= node->m_right;
         node->m_right=temp->m_left;
         if(temp->m_left){
             temp->m_left->m_parent=node;
         }
         temp->m_parent=node->m_parent;
         if(node->m_parent==nullptr){
             this->root=temp;
         }else if(node==node->m_parent->m_left){
             node->m_parent->m_left=temp;
         }else if(node== node->m_parent->m_right){
             node->m_parent->m_right=temp;
         }
         temp->m_left=node;
         node->m_parent=temp;
     }
    
 }
void right_rotate(Node<T>* node){
        Node<T>* temp=node->m_left;
        node->m_left=temp->m_right;
        if(temp->m_right){
            temp->m_right->m_parent=node;
        }
        temp->m_parent= node->m_parent;
        if(node->m_parent==nullptr){
            this->root=temp;
        }else if(node==node->m_parent->m_left){
            node->m_parent->m_left=temp;
        }else if(node== node->m_parent->m_right){
            node->m_parent->m_right=temp;
        }
        temp->m_right=node;
        node->m_parent=temp;
   }

 //splaying the node
void splay(Node<T>* node){
    while(node!=root){
        if(node->m_parent->m_parent==nullptr){
            if(node==node->m_parent->m_left){
                right_rotate(node->m_parent);
                return ;
            }else if(node==node->m_parent->m_right){
                left_rotate(node->m_parent);
                return ;
            }
        }else if(node->m_parent->m_parent!=nullptr){
            if(node==node->m_parent->m_left && node->m_parent==node->m_parent->m_parent->m_left){//leftleft case or zig zig
                right_rotate(node->m_parent->m_parent);
                right_rotate(node->m_parent);
            }else if(node==node->m_parent->m_right && node->m_parent==node->m_parent->m_parent->m_right){//rightright case or zag zag
                left_rotate(node->m_parent->m_parent);
                left_rotate(node->m_parent);
            }else if(node==node->m_parent->m_right && node->m_parent==node->m_parent->m_parent->m_left){
                left_rotate(node->m_parent);
                right_rotate(node->m_parent);
            }else{
                right_rotate(node->m_parent);
                left_rotate(node->m_parent);
            }
        }
    }
}
//level order traversal
void level_order(){
    if(this->root==nullptr){return ;}
    else{
        std::queue<Node<T>* > q;
        q.push(this->root);
        while(!q.empty()){
            Node<T>* curr_ptr=q.front();
            q.pop();
            std::cout<<curr_ptr->m_data<<" ";
            if(curr_ptr->m_left!=nullptr){
                q.push(curr_ptr->m_left);
            }
            if(curr_ptr->m_right!=nullptr){
                q.push(curr_ptr->m_right);
            }
        }

    }
}

void insert(T data){
    insert(data,this->root);
}
Node<T>* insert(T data,Node<T>* node){
    
    if(this->root==nullptr){
        this->root= new Node<T>(data);
        return this->root;
    }else{
        Node<T>* curr_ptr=node;
            if(data<node->m_data){
                if(node->m_left!=nullptr){
                    node->m_left=insert(data,node->m_left);
                }else{
                    Node<T>* new_node = new Node<T>(data);
                    curr_ptr->m_left= new_node;
                    new_node->m_parent=curr_ptr;
                    splay(new_node);
                }
                
            }else if(data> node->m_data){
                if(node->m_right!= nullptr){
                    insert(data,node->m_right);
                }else{
                    Node<T>* new_node= new Node<T>(data);
                    curr_ptr->m_right= new_node;
                    new_node->m_parent=curr_ptr;
                    splay(new_node);
                }
                
            }

        
   }
   return node;
}
};
```

> node.h

```
template<class T>

class Node{

  public:
        T m_data; // holds the key
    Node<T>* m_parent; // pointer to the parent
    Node<T>* m_left; // pointer to left child
    Node<T>* m_right; // pointer to right child
     Node(T data){
        m_data=data;
        m_left=nullptr ;
        m_right=nullptr ;
        m_parent=nullptr;
     }
     
};
```

> main.cpp

```
#include"splay_tree.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
     splay_tree<int> s1;
  
      s1.insert(10);
      s1.insert(20);
      s1.insert(15);
      s1.insert(1);

      s1.level_order();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have silly mistakes in your program. You need to change some of the names of the functions.
Here are the changes in your code :

```
 void left_rotate(Node<T>* node){
     if(node==nullptr){return ;}
     else{
         Node<T>* temp= node->m_right;
         node->m_right=temp->m_left;
         if(temp->m_left){
             temp->m_left->m_parent=node;
         }
         temp->m_parent=node->m_parent;
         if(node->m_parent==nullptr){
             this->root=temp;
         }else if(node==node->m_parent->m_left){
             node->m_parent->m_left=temp;
         }else if(node== node->m_parent->m_right){
             node->m_parent->m_right=temp;
         }
         temp->m_left=node;
         node->m_parent=temp;
     }
    
 }
void right_rotate(Node<T>* node){
        Node<T>* temp=node->m_left;
        node->m_left=temp->m_right;
        if(temp->m_right){
            temp->m_right->m_parent=node;
        }
        temp->m_parent= node->m_parent;
        if(node->m_parent==nullptr){
            this->root=temp;
        }else if(node==node->m_parent->m_left){
            node->m_parent->m_left=temp;
        }else if(node== node->m_parent->m_right){
            node->m_parent->m_right=temp;
        }
        temp->m_right=node;
        node->m_parent=temp;
   }

   //splay Function
      void splay(Node<T>* node){
        while(node->m_parent){
            if(!node->m_parent->m_parent){
                if(node==node->m_parent->m_left){//zig Rotation
                    right_rotate(node->m_parent);
                }else if(node==node->m_parent->m_right){
                    left_rotate(node->m_parent);
                }
            }
            else if(node==node->m_parent->m_left && node->m_parent==node->m_parent->m_parent->m_left){//Zig Zig 
                right_rotate(node->m_parent->m_parent);
                right_rotate(node->m_parent);
            }else if(node== node->m_parent->m_right && node->m_parent==node->m_parent->m_parent->m_right){//zag zag
                left_rotate(node->m_parent->m_parent);
                left_rotate(node->m_parent);
            }else if(node==node->m_parent->m_left && node->m_parent== node->m_parent->m_parent->m_right){
                right_rotate(node->m_parent);
                left_rotate(node->m_parent);
            }else if(node== node->m_parent->m_right && node->m_parent== node->m_parent->m_parent->m_left){
                left_rotate(node->m_parent);
                right_rotate(node->m_parent);
            }
        }
      }



    //Insert Function
void insert(T data){
    Node<T>* new_node= new Node<T>(data);
    Node<T>* y= nullptr;
    Node<T>* x= this->root;
    while (x!= nullptr){
        y=x;
        if(new_node->m_data<x->m_data){
            x= x->m_left;
        }
        else{
            x=x->m_right;
        }
    }
        // y is a m_parent of x
        new_node->m_parent=y;
        if(y==nullptr){
            this->root=new_node;
        }else if(new_node->m_data<y->m_data){
            y->m_left=new_node;
        }else{
            y->m_right=new_node;
        }
    
    splay(new_node);
}
```

What you were doing wrong?
You were doing opposite naming like left was being called as right.
I have also improved the insert function, though your's also seem to be right.
Splay function remains unchanged.